# change vuetify scss variables in specific component

Tags: vue.js, variables, sass, vuetify.js

I've used Vuetify in Vue-cli project. I have `variables.scss` file in `src/styles` directory of the project. Now I want to change the Vuetify Scss variable in only one component without effects on other components?

For example, I want to change `$icon-size, $avatar-margin-x` value in only one component. How can I do that?

Comment: Just you have to add a wrapper class and inside that, the way we do in scss you can change  the styles you want to do for any predefined vuetify class. Did you try like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for something like this:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#usage-in-templates

For globals

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass'

  @media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'md-and-down')}
    .custom-class
      display: none
</style>
```

Per component:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '~vuetify/src/components/VStepper/_variables.scss';

  .custom-class {
    padding: $stepper-step-padding;
  }
</style>
```